# My containers in portainer have disapeared and cannot be redeployed

Tags: linux, docker, containers, portainer

I'm having issues now with my portainer. I run ubuntu with docker and portainer and I ran the apt-get upgrade and install command through the terminal to update some things. now when I go to the portainer all my containers are gone and when I go to deploy them again I get the:

```
failed to deploy a stack: Creating Container xxxxx Starting Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/docker/ghost/mysql': mkdir /docker: read-only file system
```

At the time the only thing I could think of that maybe had created this issue was went ubuntu said there were updates to be installed so I let it install and then also ran the apt-get commands in terminal:

```
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install
```

My ubuntu storage has 80GB free (someone said may be a storage issue)

I was on the portainer slack channel trying to get help from a staff member he had me try "docker ps" which didn't work I had to try "sudo docker ps" which gave me that second error message listed above.https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/

```
permission denied while trying to connect to the docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/containers/json": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permissions denied
```

I also went and tried the docker group add from the docker docs and tried adding the $USER to the docker group. I have done that also, it lets me run the hello-world from the terminal but still doesn't let me deploy on portainer.

I still get the same deploy error from portainer:

```
failed to deploy a stack: Creating Container xxxxx Starting Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/docker/ghost/mysql': mkdir /docker: read-only file system
```

This was from one of the stacks I tried to redeploy since it has the /docker/"ghost"/mysql. Also, doesnt let me redeploy any other stacks tried that too.

Really unsure what to do and how to fix it since it basically now doesn't let me use any of those containers. Any help will be really appreciated, quite on edge right now! Thanks

I was kinda expecting not to have any of these issues. Not event entirely sure how it happened, I'm assuming maybe when I was using the "apt-get" commands. I don't really know myself. I would just like this fixed so I can get my data and containers back up and going on portainer. Yes, I also know portainer and docker are different and portainer is only a utility for docker.

edit: to add to this I have also re-installed portainer and docker not a full docker refresh but the standard one where it keeps some of the files since I dont want to remove some of the directories where some containers keep there configs and data files